# Python get proper line ending

Tags: python, line-endings

Is there an easy way to get the type of line ending that the current operating system uses?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

If you are operating on a file that you opened in text mode, then you are correct that line breaks all show up as '`\n`'. Otherwise, you are looking for [`os.linesep`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) .

From http://docs.python.org/library/os.html:

> os.**linesep**
>
> The string used to separate (or, rather, terminate) lines on the
>   current platform. This may be a single
>   character, such as '\n' for POSIX, or
>   multiple characters, for example,
>   '\r\n' for Windows. Do not use
>   os.linesep as a line terminator when
>   writing files opened in text mode (the
>   default); use a single '\n' instead,
>   on all platforms.

Comment: When you mean by "text mode", do you mean by non-binary mode in general?

Comment: And if you're wondering, per https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open-newline-parameter, this also works while writing files out.

Answer (score 20):

Oh, I figured it out. Apparently, [PEP-278](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/) states the following:

> Any line ending in the input file will be seen as a '\n' in Python, so little other code has to change to handle universal newlines.

Answer (score 8):

If specify test resp. binary properly when opening files, and use universal newlines, you shouldn't have to worry about different newlines most of the time.

But if you have to, use [os.linesep](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.linesep)

Answer (score 1):

os.linesep is important as it depends (as the name implied:)) on os.

E.g. on Windows, it is not "\n" but rather "\r\n".

But if you don't care about multi-platform stuff you can just use '\n'.

Comment: this directly contradicts the accepted answer which quotes the documentation, which recommends to simply use \n even on windows-textfiles (as they will be converted to \r\n when the file is opened in text-mode)