# map string position to line number in regex output

Tags: python, regex, grep, multiline

I'm working on a "grep-like" utility in Python for searching Oracle source code files.  Coding standards have changed over time, so trying to find something like "all deletes from table a.foo" could span multiple lines, or not, depending on the age of that piece of code:

```
s = """-- multiline DDL statement
DELETE
    a.foo f
WHERE
    f.bar = 'XYZ';

DELETE a.foo f
WHERE f.bar = 'ABC';

DELETE a.foo WHERE bar = 'PDQ';
"""

import re

p = re.compile( r'\bDELETE\b.+?a\.foo', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL )

for m in re.finditer( p, s ):
    print s[ m.start() : m.end() ]
```

This outputs:

```
DELETE
    a.foo
DELETE a.foo
DELETE a.foo
```

What I want:

```
[2] DELETE
[3]     a.foo
[7] DELETE a.foo
[10] DELETE a.foo
```

Is there a quick/simple/builtin way to map string indices to line numbers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
lineno = s.count("\n",0,m.start())+1
```

Comment: What if you are on a different system or you don't know what OS you are on? It could be either \n \r \f  or a combination of these.

Comment: You can always use os.linesep as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454725/python-get-proper-line-ending#454809