# Line endings and reading and writing to text files

Tags: python, file-io, line-endings

I am writing a small script that will need to read and write to *text* files on Windows and Linux and perhaps Mac even. The script will be used by users on all perhaps all of these platforms (Windows for sure) and interchangeably - so a user who wrote to a file `X` on Windows, may read the file on Linux with the script.

What precautions should I take or how should I implement my code that it is able to handle line endings across various platforms? (reading and writing)

Or this is a non-issue and Python handles everything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454725/python-get-proper-line-ending

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a non-issue, Python is smart like that. It handles line endings across platforms very well.

Comment: @A A Python is usually built with universal newline support, but you can build it without that. I'd recommend you add the `U` just to be safe. It's never been a problem for me, though, but all versions of Python might not behave the same

Comment: Ok all right, I found the answer to that. So I should not bother about it at all. That is good news. I searched for this issue and thought there were issues.

Comment: @A A nope, fortunately Python works pretty smoothly across platform. They do a good job of abstracting all the OS-specific stuff.

Answer (score 1):

A non-issue is something you don't have to pay any attention to for the rest of your life. That's not the case here, it's all too easy to mess up line-endings in Python, even.

For platform-independent *writing*, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22396206/platform-independent-way-of-writing-files)

For p-i *reading*, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10785131/line-endings-in-python)