# Save and read `\r` in a file - Python 3

Tags: python, file

I'm saving a file containing \r with :

```
with open (filepath, mode = 'w') as file:
             file.write(content)
```

And I read it with :

```
with open (filepath, mode = 'r') as file:
             content = file.read()
```

I know that the characters \r are present in the saved file, but opening it with Python, they are replaced with \n.

So, how can I open my file with the \r ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open-newline-parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file with `rb` instead of `r` (and `wb` instead of `w`) . This tells python to open in binary mode, and if you open without it (in text mode) python automatically normalizes end of line chars.

If you want to open in text mode, use the `newline = ''` parameter suggested in the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

By default python will translate the line endings to `\n` automatically when it reads a text file. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10785131/line-endings-in-python) for a bit more info on line endings.

if you call `open(filepath, mode='w', newline='')` it should prevent python from translating those line endings.