# platform independent way of writing files

Tags: python

```
def writeFile(filename):
    prose = r"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>"
    startTag = r'<Books>'
    endTag = r'</Books>'
    with open(filename, "+a" ) as f:
        f.write(prose)
        f.write('\n')
        f.write(startTag)
        f.write('\n')
        f.write(endTag)
```

How do i make this function platform independent so it can work on Windows and Linux/Unix as well
Since /n is the new line character on windows.

I am on Python 3.3

Comment: "Since /n is the new line character on windows" - it isn't. Newline on windows is `\r\n`, two characters. In any case, you're opening the file in text mode (the default), so it should work fine.

Comment: python handles newline conversion for you.  `\n` just works.

Comment: You may want to specify an encoding of `'utf-8'` to the `open` call, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to look in to [os](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) module. Especially check `os.linesep` and `os.sep`.

`os.linesep` will give you give correct new line separator, you don't need to check the platorm/os version

os.sep will give you separator for pathname components and again you don't need to check the platform/os version