# In python carriage return \r returns a musical note

Tags: python, printing, raspberry-pi, raspbian, carriage-return

```
print "-------------------\r"
```

produces a musical note instead doing the carriage return. Why?

Thanks in advance for reply.

EDIT: I was using it in this code in order to change dinamically data by 'print' instead to re-print it all:

```
import math
import time

    while True:
        reading = read_world_2c(0x43) #it's a function for reading data from a sensor
        print "data:     \r", reading
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: How are you running this?

Comment: OS? Version? Doesn't do it for me using Windows 7 3.4.0 in the IPython console.

Comment: For most people it will not, in actual fact, produce a musical note. You'll have to provide more context here, like in what environment you are running this.

Comment: I am sorry. I am using Debian (Linux) in RaspberryPi with Python 2 and IDLE as IDE.

Comment: I have found this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122385/dynamic-terminal-printing-with-python but also in this case it returns the musical note in \r position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That musical note is the symbol for line breaks. If you have MS Word or Notepad++ or similar, open or type some text and then find the menu command for "show nonprinting characters ". You will see those "musical notes" at the end of each line.

Comment: Is there a way to replace 'break' with the carriage return \r for 'print' in Python?

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with your code but I'm not a Python programmer. Try \n or os.linesep : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454725/python-get-proper-line-ending

Comment: the only '\n' works. I have used os.linesep in the shell and it returns only '\n'. I have read that it would return '\r\n'.

Comment: @Orlok  [This Stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433188/r-n-r-n-what-is-the-difference-between-them) can tell you more about \r, \n, and \r\n.

Comment: I do not see any char.  The IDLE doc, Help ==> IDLE Help, section User output in Shell discusses the printing of control characters.  Result depends on OS and font, and possibly tcl/tk version.