# Pandas DataFrame.to_csv creating a new line when saving a dataframe to file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a dataframe `df_new` which looks like:

[image]

And when I use the command:

```
df_new.to_csv(csv+'_filtered.csv', index=False)
```

I generate a csv file that suddenly breaks the row 24 before the 2 last columns, generating a new undesirable row which is completely empty, except the data of the last 2 columns that should be in the previous row:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong to save this file?

Comment: Maybe there is a newline in the data of line 23?

Comment: Can you add the line as it is originally ? perhaps it includes a new line

Comment: There is a `\r` at the end of the URL on row 21. I don't know if that is the proper situation, but [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34550393/18125313) may load correctly.

Comment: @ken, It was exactly this and your link solved my problem. If you want to post it as an answer, I will accept it

Comment: Glad I could help. Just posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `\r` at the end of the URL on row 21. I don't know if that is the proper situation, but [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34550393/18125313) may load correctly.